# Set Text Wrapping for an AutoGenerated DataGrid TextBox using a behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am attempting to set an auto-generated `DataGrid` column's `TextBox` to wrap text using a behavior. However, setting the property during the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event does not work.  Am I setting the correct property or is there some problem?

Here is the XAML for the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TableGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoHeaderBehavior/>
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

And here is the code for the behavior:

```
public class AutoHeaderBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
      base.OnAttached();
      this.AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn += OnGeneratingColumn;
   }

   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
      this.AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn -= OnGeneratingColumn;
      base.OnDetaching();
   }

   private void OnGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.PropertyDescriptor is PropertyDescriptor descriptor)
      {
         e.Column.Header = descriptor.DisplayName ?? descriptor.Name;
         if (descriptor.DisplayName == "Description")
         {
            var wrapping = new Setter() { Property = TextBox.TextWrappingProperty, Value = TextWrapping.Wrap };
            var style = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
            style.Setters.Add(wrapping);
            (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).ElementStyle = style;
            e.Column.Width = 300;
         }
      }
      else
         e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after fiddling around with this problem for several hours I decided to resolve the issue by replacing the column entirely.

```
private void OnGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyDescriptor is PropertyDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        e.Column.Header = descriptor.DisplayName ?? descriptor.Name;
        if (descriptor.DisplayName == "Description")
        {
            var column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            var element = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            var binding = new Binding("Description");
            var template = new DataTemplate();

            element.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
            element.SetValue(TextBox.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap);
            template.VisualTree = element;
            template.Seal();
            column.CellTemplate = template;
            column.Header = e.Column.Header;
            column.Width = 300;
                
            e.Column = column;
        }
    }
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A data grid column has two different modes, *Non-Edit* and *Edit*, for [`DataGridTextColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn?view=netcore-3.1):

- In non-edit mode, it displays a `TextBlock` using the style in the [`ElementStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle?view=netcore-3.1) property.
- In edit mode, it displays a `TextBox` using the style in the [`EditingElementStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.editingelementstyle?view=netcore-3.1) property.

The issue in your code is that you apply the editing style to the non-edit style property. I have adapted your behavior code to wrap the text in edit and non-edit mode. If you want text wrapping in edit mode only, just remove the assignment of the `ElementStyle` property and the corresponding style.

```
public class AutoHeaderBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
      base.OnAttached();
      AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn += OnGeneratingColumn;
   }

   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
      AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn -= OnGeneratingColumn;
      base.OnDetaching();
   }

   private void OnGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.PropertyDescriptor is PropertyDescriptor descriptor)
      {
         e.Column.Header = descriptor.DisplayName ?? descriptor.Name;
         if (descriptor.DisplayName == "Description")
         {
            var textWrappingSetter = new Setter
            {
               Property = TextBox.TextWrappingProperty,
               Value = TextWrapping.Wrap
            };

            // Style for non-edit mode (TextBlock)
            var elementStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
            elementStyle.Setters.Add(textWrappingSetter);

            // Style for edit mode (TextBox)
            var editingElementStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
            editingElementStyle.Setters.Add(textWrappingSetter);

            var dataGridTextColumn = (DataGridTextColumn)e.Column;
            dataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle = elementStyle;
            dataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle = editingElementStyle;

            e.Column.Width = 300;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         e.Cancel = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I modified the code as indicated; unfortunately, the TextBox is still not wrapping.  However, thanks for the info on the two edit/non-edit styles; good info to know.  I did come up with an entirely different solution (adding answer).

Comment: @Los2000 I tested it and it works, maybe there is a different issue. I recommend you to test this in a blank solution or project. It could help to figure out what is wrong. It is good that you found  a solution that works for you, however it seems to add complexity including the creation of a new template column with bindings, so it might be worth investigating the issue, but if it fits your requirements it is fine, too.

Comment: I agree it does add complexity, and fiddling around with a framework object's binding and template outside of XAML has a bit of a code smell to me; which is why I asked the original question I did.  Regardless, anyone who has the same issue will be able find a solution that works.  I'll leave a comment if I figure out why your solution didn't work for me.